# Authenticator.Instance.Login with sessionKey keeps faulting after first error for all clients

Tags: devforce

We have a client-server application that in some cases needs to execute a server side service without having a client EntityManager. The client application passes a valid sessionKey to the server which performs an Authenticator.Instance.Login(sessionKey) call and obtain a valid AuthenticationContext which can be used to correctly connect the server side's EntityManager.

Every thing is working fine until the server is restarted. All the previously cached sessionKeys become invalid as expected.

New client connections are working fine and calls with new generated sessionKeys are also working fine.

When a client application try to make a call to the service with an invalid sessionKey a LoginException is thrown as expected and asks for ReLogin.
At this point everything is working as expected.

The problem is that from this moment, all the new calls, even with a valid sessionKey, will throw the same last exception and all the new clients will recieve the same exception.

It seems that EntityServer.SessionManager.Login(sessionKey) is queing the sessionKeys to connect and once one call failed it is always failing.

Is there any way to clear the EntityServer.SessionManager's faulting sessionKeys list after a failing attempt ?

This issue is extremely harmful, as we have to ensute that all the clients are shutdown before restarting the server !